# Defining a variable for 2 objects' concurrently

Tags: punctuation

In my text I have this sentence: "In equations X and Y, Z = 1"

Is the comma fine or should it be a colon?

I.e. should it be:

"In equations X and Y, Z = 1"

or

"In equations X and Y: Z = 1"

Comment: Note that Z=1 in both equations X and Y.

Comment: You _do_ need a comma after the introductory element OK, if you insist on using it. 'Aka' does not mean 'in other words'. Hurting people? You're potentially misleading people trying to get to grips with acceptable English. // Mathematics SE  is the place to ask this; punctuation usages in maths often differ from those accepted in standard English. A comma between variables is often connected to an ordered pair; colons are used in maths to mean 'is to' in ratios, 'such that' in specifying subsets. Jim's suggestion is sensible and would be understood by anyone speaking English

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit with the aims of Mathematics or Mathematics Educators.